# IE 8 scripts stopped working all of a sudden

Tags: windows-7, asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, javascript

We use a .NET based web application for our daily transactions.

This web application uses java scripts and vb scripts extensively.  We are able to connect to the site and authenticate.  However the site is not fully functional when we login from one particular LAN but the site works fine when we login from else where.

Any ideas what could be the problem or if you have faced such issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Fiddler?  It is generally useful to determine where your web application is breaking:

http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/version.asp